# "git restore --staged" returns an error "could not resolve HEAD"

Tags: git

I have created a Git repository locally by using the command `git init`.

Then mistakenly added all files for staging by entering `git add .`
But I want to unstage some files which I don't want to commit.

But when I enter `git restore --staged <file/folder name>`, it states the following:

```
fatal: could not resolve HEAD
```

I figured out this occurred due to my branch main having no commits yet. So, is it possible to exclude some files from staging before I can commit? If so, how can I achieve it?

Comment: You can just `git reset` to unstage the files. Or  just `rm -rf .git; git init`.

Comment: That’s a pretty bad error message for what is supposed to be a new-and-improved command (less backwards compatibility concerns).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `git reset` to remove all files from stage or `git reset /path/to/file`